# About First Order Logic an Godel incompleness theory.

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness, type-theory

There's something I'm failing to grasp: Are Gödel's theorems of incompleteness a first order logic result or a second order logic result? What confuses me is the fact that in Gödel's original work, he talks about predicate variables which I believe are second order entities, however I think that by using "Type Theory" it is possible to talk about predicate variables with out using second order logic. Is this correct?

Comment: [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) applies to first-order theories. Regarding [SOL](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#PropSecoOrdeForm), you have to recall that there is **no** *complete* proof system for FOL.

Comment: If we "restrict" to an *effective* proof system that is sound for SOL, we have that this proof system is not complete, i.e. there is a logical truth that is not a theorem of it. The proof is based exactly on the possibility of reproducing in it the construction of Godel’s incompleteness theorem. See E.Jerzak, [Second Order Logic](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf).

Comment: And yes, G's original proof used a "simplified" version of *Principia Mathematica*'s [Type Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) (i.e. an High-Order Logic) with a suitable version of Peano's axioms.

Comment: For details, see Stewart Shapiro, [Foundations without Foundationalism : A Case for Second-Order Logic (Clarendon Press, 1991)](https://books.google.it/books?id=xm5eWgjpYU0C&printsec=frontcover), page 66 for the proof system for full SOL; page 71-on for its semantics; page 82 for second-order PA and its *categoricity*.

Comment: Wait, the incompleteness here referes to the proof system being incomplete while Godel's completeness thoerems referes to the relationship betweeen semantics and syntaxis in FOL?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "Regarding SOL, you have to recall that there is no complete proof system for FOL." I think that "FOL" should be an "SOL."